# How to get Mock to return null if setup isn't exactly matched

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I'm trying to test a function and I want a mock to return a null if the setup isn't matched exactly.  But it's returning a 'mocked' object; an object with default values.  I've tried setting the mock.SetReturnsDefault to null and mock.DefaultValue = null, with no change.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C", 1)]
[InlineData("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C", 2)]
[InlineData("985F7161-1B0F-4EEA-9572-02D6D13D712B", 1)]
public async Task Get_ShouldReturn1TierSet_GivenAProgram_And_AnExistingId(Guid programId, int id)
{
    _tierSetService.Setup(x => x.GetTierSet(1, new Guid("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C"))).ReturnsAsync(new TierSet()
    {
        Id = 1,
        StartDate = DateTime.Now,
        EndDate = DateTime.Now,
        Name = "Some Tier Set",
        TierSetState = Core.Constants.TierSetState.Draft,
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
        Program = new Domain.Models.Program(){ },
        DisplayTierSet = false
    });

    var actual = await _controller.Get(programId, id);
    if (programId == new Guid("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C") && id == 1)
    {
        Assert.NotNull(actual);
    }
    else
    {
        Assert.Null(actual);
    }
}
```

I added another test and set up the mock to return null with `It.IsAny<>()` arguments, and that works as expected.
Any reason it wouldn't return null or how to guarantee it will return null if the setup isn't matched?

Comment: In your shared code I don't who will call _tierSetService.Setup.GetTierSet. But I guess your _controller will call that? 
In that case, _tierSetService.Setup for different GPID's and Combination to return null and non nullable value. You can use your test method to define expected output as well like: Get_ShouldReturn1TierSet_GivenAProgram_And_AnExistingId(Guid programId, int id, bool expectedResult)

[InlineData("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C", 1, true)]
[InlineData("DFF0DF04-0D3F-419B-82FB-23F0A8E2452C", 2, false)]
[InlineData("985F7161-1B0F-4EEA-9572-02D6D13D712B", 1, true)]

Comment: Yes, the controller will call the mock.  Your suggestion for the expected value is probably better than the if/else, but doesn't help with the mock not returning null.

Comment: You are missing my point, _tierSetService.Setup for each different combination of ID/Guid whatever you have. You can't just return new TierSet for "1" id. If you expect to return null for id "2" then just _tierSetService.Setup(2,......).returns(null)
So you need to do ".setup" for each combination of your expected calls to that moq.

Comment: Got you.  A slight modification, I made a generic `
            _tierSetService.Setup(x => x.GetTierSet(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Guid>())).ReturnsAsync((TierSet)null);`, with my specific one after that, then everything worked, without the additional parameter.  Thanks.  If you make an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks and Glad that it worked. I have added it as the answer. May not be the exact working code, but just to demonstrate how we can "Setup" multiple expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that we can close this question here. OP mentioned that the suggestions I provided in the comments resolved his issue. Adding this post here and for anyone looking for an answer about similar behavior, the solution is to set multiple setups on your Mock object to return the expected value. Example

```
    _tierSetService.Setup(x => x.GetTierSet(1, It.IsAny<Guid>))).ReturnsAsync(new TierSet()
    {
        Id = 1
    });

    _tierSetService.Setup(x => x.GetTierSet(2, It.IsAny<Guid>()))).ReturnsAsync(null));
```

So this way when the proxy calls the _tierSetService.GetTierSet with the matching "arguments", will try to match the correct fake and return the same.